# Better or more idiomatic way to apply a sequence of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, linked-list, higher-order-functions

This is one of my Haskell solutions to a variation of the N-Queens problem, where the queens can move like knights in addition to their normal moves.  It has been optimized somewhat to avoid investigating redundant combinations.

```
place :: Int -> [[Int]]
place 0 = [[]]
place n = go $ take n $ repeat [1..n] 
    where go [] = [[]]
          go (row:rest) = do
                q <- row 
                qs <- go $ safe q rest
                return (q : qs)
          safe q = notK q . notD q . notC q
          notC q = map (filter (/= q))
          notD q = (map (\(x, r) -> filter (\y -> abs(y - q) /= x) r)) . (zip [1..])
          notK q = map (\(f, r) -> filter f r) . (zip (kFilters q))
          kFilters q = (\x -> abs (x - q) /= 2) : (\x -> abs (x - q) > 1) : (repeat (const True))

solutions = length . place

main = do
    n <- readLn
    putStrLn $ show $ solutions n
```

I am satisfied with the performance, but I feel there must be a more elegant way to apply a series of functions (in this case, filters) to a list.

In each iteration of the recursive function `go`, the top row of the board is selected and then for each position in sequence a queen is positioned and the function recurs with a filtered copy of the rest of the board, so that each iteration has only safe squares to choose from.  The `safe` function applies three filters to the board:

1. `notC` removes all spaces in the same column as the new queen.
2. `notD` removes any spaces on a diagonal from the new queen.
3. `notK` removes knight moves from the next two lines.

I feel that `notK` in particular could be implemented more cleanly and idiomatically but I couldn't see a better way to apply one function to the first item of a list, another to the second and something else to the rest.  And using `zip` does save me from having to check for the end of the board.

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a better way to write `notD`.  So I am looking for more expressive ways to apply a sequence of varying functions to successive list items.

**UPDATE**:

I realise that I can use `uncurry` to clean up `notK`...

```
        notK q = map (uncurry filter) . (zip (kFilters q))
```

and the two filters in Kfilters can be written in dot notation...

```
        ((/= 2) . abs . subtract q) : ((/= 1) . abs . subtract q) : ...
```

which allows the kFilters line to be rendered as

```
        kFilters = (f 2) : (f 1) : (repeat (const True))
```

but this doesn't actually change my original question.  I'm still looking for a better mechanism for applying a varying sequence of functions to a list.

Answer (score 6):

```
notK q = map (uncurry filter) . (zip (kFilters q))
```

is equivalent to

```
notK q rows = zipWith filter (kFilters q) rows
```

Onto making above Haskell less *idiomatic* and less *pointfree* and more *readable*.

```
notC q = map (filter (/= q))
notD q = (map (\(x, r) -> filter (\y -> abs(y - q) /= x) r)) . (zip [1..])
notK q = map (\(f, r) -> filter f r) . (zip (kFilters q))
```

These three are logically similar but structurally dissimilar.

First let's factor out common components, give them meaningful names, and some comments to help those readers without the Developer's Manual.

```
-- a new queen placed in column q
-- would take a piece placed in column x
-- n rows down
-- because (r, q) and (r+n, x)

-- are on the same column
sameColumn q n x = x == q

-- are on the same diagonal
sameDiagonal q n x = abs(x - q) == n

-- or (n, |q - x|) is in [(1,2),(2,1)]
onKnightMove :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
onKnightMove q n x = (n, abs(x - q)) `elem` [(1,2),(2,1)]
```

The last one needs a better name still, oh well. At least they are of the same form, with parameter name use consistent among them (and elsewhere).

```
rowFilterList :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool) -> [Int -> Bool]
rowFilterList q pred = map (\n x -> not $ pred q n x) [1..]
```

such that `kFilters q = rowFilterList q onKnightMove`

```
filterRows :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool) -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
filterRows q pred rows = zipWith filter (rowFilterList q pred) rows
```

This way `notC q = filterRows q sameColumn` and `notD q = filterRows q sameDiagonal`

`notK q . notD q . notC q` a repetition is evident. And we now can factor it out easily.

```
filterWithAll :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool] -> [[Int]]
filterWithAll q rows preds = foldl (\rows' pred -> filterRows q pred rows') rows preds
```

such that `safe q rows = filterWithAll q rows [sameColumn, sameDiagonal, onKnightMove]`

By factoring out `[sameColumn, sameDiagonal, onKnightMove]` as a parameter to `place n` one could easily generalize `place` from n super-queens to n queens or n rooks.